# Registering chromium-browser for MarkDown preview plug-in in Sublime Text 2 fails

Tags: sublimetext2, markdown, chromium

Using Linux, Sublime 2, open markdown inside chromium instead firefox (or other).
There are suggestions to set

```
webbroser.register('chromium-browser', ??)
```

and then use

```
webbrowser.get('chromium-browser').open("file://" + output.name)
```

instead of

```
webbrowser.open("file://" + output.name)
```

in MarkdownBuild.py to build html from markdown into chromium-browser instead default (firefox). But I can't get it working...

## **Update**

cat ~/.zshrc : `export BROWSER=chromium-browser` > `$BROWSER` shows up a new window of chromium. All links from skype or any chat are retrieved by chromium. But still sublime `Ctrl+B` opens Firefox.

Comment: How it fails? Are you sure your edited code is used? Test the code in a standalone Python script first and you get more debug options and output.

Comment: It's a question more about Sublime, not python. Using webbrowser in python console works fine, but 'build' option in sublime fails to open the browser i want.